# HTML Manipulation

Tags: c#, html, navigation

I have some HTML code that I'm using for navigation on my website.

I have an unordered list tag (`<ul>`) that contains list items (`<li>`), which themselves might have unordered lists within them.

In my C# back end, I have the HTML in a string and I want to manipulate this list to remove the top level.

For example:

http://pastebin.com/2Gt5xu3d

When on the "History","Contact","Email" or "Phone" page would become:

http://pastebin.com/Mpzssy21

So no matter what level you are at, I want to remove everything at the top level, except the `<ul>` you're currently in.

I'm not really sure where to start. Is there an easy way to manipulate HTML in this way using C#?

EDIT:
I now have the HTML in a HtmlDocument using the HTML Agility Pack. Does anyone have any ideas how I could proceed?

Comment: Are you trying to crawl/parse? Or are you generating the site on the fly with something like ASP.NET?

Comment: This specific navigation I'm generating in the C# and then adding to the site. The original list I have been passed by my CMS framework, and I want to manipulate it as described. So I have the HTML in a string in my C#, and just want to know how I could alter it to reach my desired output.

Comment: Instead of sticking everything into a string, why don't you generate the markup using literals (as an example)? This probably won't solve your problem, but at least would make things more clear. If you're trying to manipulate the DOM on a client side event (click, etc), you'll need Javascript to achieve this.

Comment: I'm not trying to do this client side. It's server-side in C# before the page is rendered.

Comment: I think you can control it with CSS. All child pages will have it's  css style tag (or css file).

Comment: What do you mean control it by CSS?

Comment: If you want to hide some tags on parent page, you can write css in child page

Comment: I don't want to hide tags on the parent page. And all the <li> items will have the same class.

Comment: Take a look at the HtmlAgilityPack - http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/

Comment: I see you decided to use the HtmlAgilityPack :-) I've not used it extensively, but it appears to be very flexible (despite that it didn't do what I wanted, hence why I haven't used it much) - There should be some examples on the codeplex site on how to traverse the document. I think you may need to look into xPath. I think it might also support LINQ Queries. Admittedly if you're not just querying the document, you might want to use something else to traverse it properly.

Comment: It does look like it could be useful, but I'm not really sure how to solve my problem logically, so at the moment I'm still stuck.